# Exoplayer FFmpeg audio Decoder?

Tags: exoplayer

*Does anyone working on building FFmpeg audio decoder in Exoplayer any sample video URL about How to Extension FFmpeg in exoplayer.*

Comment: Have you found out anything?

Answer (score 0):

Add ffmpeg module from extensions directory from the offical exoplayer sample. [Download here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/extensions/ffmpeg),Then you can use it with this code.

**Kotlin:**

```
val renderersFactory = DefaultRenderersFactory(this)
renderersFactory.setExtensionRendererMode(DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER)
```

**Then pass it while building exoplayer instance**

```
exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .setRenderersFactory(renderersFactory)
            ......
```